# Ubuntu CVE Score - Gained acces level:None - Does it mean personal data is safe on ubuntu?

Tags: vulnerability, cve

I was studying the following page listing all the vulnerabilities of ubuntu. [CVE Ubuntu](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=51&product_id=&version_id=&page=2&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=85&sha=8237390084e629dfe89c8a328f07c06bdd1c8a8f)

What I found surprising is that all vulnerabilities report that "gained access level: None". Does that mean that there does not exist any known vulnerability which lets an attacker access your data? Does this presume that the data is encrypted with out of the box eCryptfs encryption or is it even safe without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misinterpreted quite a few things and made some assumptions:

1. That link shows only vulnerabilities with a limited scope and they end at 2018. There have been more since that date, so you can't make an assessment of a current version of Ubuntu from that list.
2. If you search for any other product, you will see that they all have "gained access level: none", even ones where the vulnerability is to gain admin privileges (including Windows XP).
3. "gained access level" has nothing to do with the level of access to "your data"
4. No presumptions can be made about data encryption

Comment: Does that mean that the attribute "Gained access level" does not list the attribute "gained access level" correctly?

Comment: I'm not saying that at all. I'm saying that I cannot find a definition for what that quality is supposed to represent on that site and I cannot find any entry in the database that has a different value.